# Cisco 5505 ASA firewall how to tell one interface to only allow connections from a specific IP address

Tags: networking, cisco, cisco-asa

- Interface 1 connects to WAN
- Interface 2 connects to PROXY
- PROXY has an ip of 192.168.1.2

How to I tell the ASA 5505 to only allow connections from 192.168.1.2 through interface 2? I can use ADSM or Console command line..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `inside` and `outside` interface labeling... Management access can be limited via:

For ASDM access:
`http 192.168.1.2 255.255.255.255 inside`

For telnet access:
`telnet 192.168.1.2 255.255.255.255 inside`

For general network traffic, you'd establish an access rule... Inbound-to-outbound.

Something like: `access-list inside_access_in extended permit ip 192.168.1.2 255.255.255.255 any`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've named the internal interface inside, here's what it would look like:

> access-list inside_access_in extended permit ip host 192.168.1.2 any
>   access-group inside_access_in in interface inside